# Does openSL support "returning decode audio buffer" for MP3/AAC?

Tags: android-ndk, audio

Does openSL support "returning decode audio buffer" for MP3/AAC, as Open Max IL does?
I am creating an app that has mp3/aac as input and want to use openSL as a decoder, not the player. I need decoded PCM data back to my app, and I want to play / do something else with that buffer later.

I can't find any related APIs for this in opensl spec.

Comment: Did you find anything that helped?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but perhaps you could set up a data source using as a URI data locator using MIME format with an Android audio buffer as the sink, then access the decoded data that way?